# What is AsyncCallBack in Android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

Can anyone give me a clear description of what is AsyncCallBack? Does it exist in the latest android version? Because I am directed to AsyncTask when I search for AsyncCallBack.... Are these both same? Does anyone have an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you check the documentation? Hint: AsyncCallback's full class name is com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback, so it's not part of the basic Android API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no class named AsyncCallback in android.  I think what you are looking for is AsyncTask which is a way to run a piece of code on another Thread so the UI won't be blocked, and receive it's results on the UI thread.  For example, say you want to talk to a server on the internet in response to the user clicking something in the UI, then receive some result from the server, and update the UI.  AsyncTask makes doing this very easy compared to doing regular threading code because threading lifecycle and communication back to the UI thread is handled for you.  As a bonus there is also support for canceling a background task, but you have to write the code to handle it when cancel is called.  It doesn't do it without some work on your side.

Comment: Thank you chubbard... youe explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think the terms may be mixed up here, there isn't an `AsyncCallback` in Android (as far as I know). There is however very widely used `AsyncCallback` interface in GWT (Google Web Toolkit): http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback.html.

In Android you use `AsyncTask` to easily run background operations asynchronously on a separate Thread from the main UI/app thread: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Here is a good intro article on `AsyncTask`: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html.

Comment: Thanks for the help charlie. appreciate it. I was actually looking for AsyncTask.